# Geometric product of 2 r-blades

Tags: inner-products, exterior-algebra, geometric-algebras

In some lecture notes the geometric product of a $r$-blade $A_r$ and an $s$-blade $B_s$ is given as:

$A_r B_s = \langle A_r B_s\rangle_{|r-s|} + \langle A_r B_s\rangle_{|r-s|+2} +... + \langle A_r B_s\rangle_{r+s}$

where dot means the lowest and wedge means the highest terms in this expansion:

$A_r \cdot B_s = \langle A_r B_s\rangle_{|r-s|}\\
A_r \wedge B_s = \langle A_r B_s\rangle_{r+s}$

So if I have $A_2 = e_1 \wedge e_2$ and $B_2 = b e_1 \wedge e_2$ where $b$ is a scalar and $I_2$ means the pseudoscalar $(I_2^2=-1)$ I get:

$ \overbrace{(e_1 \wedge e_2)(e_1 \wedge e_2)}^{I_2^2=-1}=\overbrace{\Big\langle(e_1 \wedge e_2)(e_1 \wedge e_2)\Big\rangle_0}^{=1} +\Big\langle(e_1 \wedge e_2)(e_1 \wedge e_2)\Big\rangle_{2}+\overbrace{\Big\langle(e_1 \wedge e_2)(e_1 \wedge e_2)\Big\rangle_{4}}^{e_1\wedge e_2 \wedge e_1\wedge e_2=0}$

My question is now what is this middle term in the expansion and is this expansion even true when $r=s$, because then this middle term would need to give $-2$, which seems very weird. Or is the problem that $A$ and $B$ are basically the same blade up to a scalar? Where are my mistakes here?

Comment: I've tried to improve the TeX a bit, including replacing `<` and `>` by `\langle` and `\rangle` respectively. I assume that is what you meant have there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $e_1$ and $e_2$ are orthonormal, so $e_1\wedge e_2=e_1e_2$.

Let $X=(e_1\wedge e_2)(e_1\wedge e_2)$. You've noted on the left side of your last equation that this is

$$X=(e_1e_2)(e_1e_2)=e_1e_2e_1e_2=e_1(e_2e_1)e_2=e_1(-e_1e_2)e_2=-(e_1e_1)(e_2e_2)=-(1)(1)$$
$$=-1.$$

This is a scalar, i.e. a $0$-vector, so $\langle X\rangle_0=X=-1$. It has no higher-grade parts, so $\langle X\rangle_2=\langle X\rangle_4=0$.

But then on the right side of your last equation you claim that $\langle X\rangle_0=+1$. Where did this come from? Have you been given several definitions of the dot product of two blades? In fact we have $(e_1\wedge e_2)\cdot(e_1\wedge e_2)=-1$, not $+1$.

---

The expansion in your first equation is correct, for any $r$ and $s$, for any $A=\langle A\rangle_r$ and $B=\langle B\rangle_s$. (But when $s=1$ there are only two terms, grades $r-1$ and $r+1$. And when $s=0$ there is only one term, grade $r$.) That expansion is not a definition, though. The geometric product is often defined implicitly, by the properties it's supposed to have.

See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4565451/472818) for an alternative, explicit definition, though it takes some work to show that it's associative, and that it doesn't really depend on the basis, etc.